iPhone activity data log with timestamps
I’m trying to find the log that the battery app uses, so anyone can know how long they used the Lock Screen with time stamps, or when the screen turned on with time stamps, any logs to tell when the iPhone was being used, it already shows in the battery app with no timestamps
Just trying to find when the phone was being used for investigation
